# Fetch records from parent table only, using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

I have following entities in my project(childs are more than two):

[image]

Is there any way to load records from parent table only(**without any extra joins**), using `EF` when I used `TPT` strategy for my inheritance?

by following codes:

```
var result = ctx.Parents.Find(5);
//or
var result = ctx.Parents.OfType<Parent>().Find(5);
```

`EF` generates a huge `SQL` query! 
(in my real model I have more than 2 childs)

Comment: Have you tired `var result = ctx.Parents.Find(5);`

Comment: @CodeNotFound: yeah, the result has no different.

Comment: Maybe you must look at SQL View :)

Answer (score 2):

Whether you query `ctx.Parents` or `ctx.Parents.OfType<Parent>()`, you always ask EF to get *all* `Parent` entities meeting a condition (`Id == 5`, in this case). EF can't know in advance whether this will be a subtyped or a non-subtyped `Parent` entity (which it could, if `Parent` isn't abstract), so it always has to execute the full query.

TPT is not a very query-friendly model. I wouldn't use it (and avoid inheritance as much as possible, for that matter).

Comment: Which inheritance strategy do you suggest that is more query-friendly model?

Comment: The two others, TPH and TPC are better in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Create new child class that hasn't any property

```
[Table("EmptyChild")]
public class EmptyChild: Parent
{

}
```

and now select with raw query:

```
public Parent GetParent(Guid id)
{
    var parent = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<EmptyChild>("Select * from Parents where Id=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", id)).FirstOrDefault();

    return parent as Parent ;
}
```